# Is there a ipython server pre shutdown hook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to run a small bit of python code when the notebook server gets a shutdown signal, is there a hook for this in the configuration?

Comment: Current versions of IPython have [shutdown_hook](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.hooks.html#IPython.core.hooks.shutdown_hook), this might help.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499748/override-ipython-exit-function-or-add-hooks-in-to-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything IPython specific. You can use the atexit module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) to run code before the Python interpreter quits.

Comment: I thought so as well, but now I'm not so sure. There's a chance at `atexit` hook won't get invoked, see here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9061