# Override ipython exit function - or add hooks in to it

Tags: python, shell, ipython

In my project [manage](http://github.com/rochacbruno/manage), I am embedding iPython with:

```
from IPython import start_ipython
from traitlets.config import Config
c = Config()
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.banner2 = "Welcome to my shell"
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']
start_ipython(argv=[], user_ns={}, config=c)
```

It works well and opens my iPython console, but to leave ipython I can just type `exit` or `exit()` or press `ctrl+D`.

What I want to do is to add an `exit hook` or replace that `exit` command with something else.

Lets say I have a function.

```
def teardown_my_shell():
    # things I want to happen when iPython exits
```

How do I register that function to be executed when I `exit` or even how to make `exit` to execute that function?

NOTE: I tried to pass `user_ns={'exit': teardown_my_shell}` and doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thanks to @user2357112, I learned how to create an extension and register a hook, but I figured out that `shutdown_hook`is deprecated.

The right way is simply.

```
import atexit

def teardown_my_shell():
    # things I want to happen when iPython exits

atexit.register(teardown_my_shell)
```

Answer (score 2):

Googling [IPython exit hook](https://www.google.com/search?q=ipython%20exit%20hook) turns up [`IPython.core.hooks`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.hooks.html?highlight=core.hooks#module-IPython.core.hooks). From that documentation, it looks like you can define an exit hook in an [IPython extension](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/config/extensions/index.html) and register it with the IPython instance's `set_hook` method:

```
# whateveryoucallyourextension.py

import IPython.core.error

def shutdown_hook(ipython):
    do_whatever()
    raise IPython.core.error.TryNext

def load_ipython_extension(ipython)
    ipython.set_hook('shutdown_hook', shutdown_hook)
```

You'll have to add the extension to your `c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions`.

Comment: The method of registering an extension works, but I found that shutdown_hook is deprecated, I am goin to put the solution as anwer

Comment: @rochacbruno: Huh. That wasn't in the documentation I found, but Google suggests you're right. I figured shutdown_hook was for when you want to do something when the IPython instance is shutting down, but the Python interpreter itself might still remain active.

Comment: this seems to be deprecated: `UserWarning: Hook shutdown_hook is deprecated. Use the atexit module instead.`